# How do I get Adobe Flash Player installed on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: flash

I have been having trouble with this. My computer in Ubuntu Linux and I know it's Ubuntu 13.0 something or higher. I've tried installing flash player and it gives me this error message "There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources."
I tried doing what I saw one person say online and download something called "pepperflashplugin-nonfree", and it is still giving me the same error message! Please help me!

Comment: "Ubuntu 13.0 something or higher" What's the output of: cat /etc/issue

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal (push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

After that (assuming you use Firefox), make sure you get the Shockwave Flash add-on. You can do that by opening Firefox, pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and then searching for Shockwave Flash.

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can install adobe-flashplugin, Adobe® Flash® Player is a cross-platform, browser-based application runtime that provides uncompromised viewing of expressive applications, content, and videos across browsers and operating systems.

The following package provides plugins compatible with both Chromium and Mozilla based web browsers. To install adobe-flashplugin, type these command in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Better if you give some words explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Centre(Alt+F2 and search Software-Centre)
2. Search for adobe flash plugin and install it.